# Grails, save doesn't save when objects is updated in a service

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Having a domain that is manipulated from a service and then trying to save that doesn't work even though I use: `save(flush:true, failOnError:true)` and `validate()` returns true and `hasErrors()` returns false.

I do a call from bootstrap:

```
def timeKeeperService
def init = { servletContext ->
    def TimeKeeper tk = TimeKeeper.findByName('MAIN')?:new TimeKeeper(name:'MAIN').save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    tk = timeKeeperService.initialize()
    tk = timeKeeperService.workStart()
```

The Domain:

```
class TimeKeeper {

    String name
    Date dateCreated
    Date dateUpdated
    Date workStart
    Date workEnd

    def initialize() {
        println("TimeKeeper initialize...")
        workStart = null
        workEnd = null
    }


    def workStart() {
       if (workStart == null) {
          println("TimeKeeper - workStart")
          workEnd = null
           workStart = new Date()  
       } else {

       }
           println("TimeKeeper - workStart: "+workStart)
    }

    def workEnd() {
        if (workEnd == null) {
            workStart = null
            workEnd = new Date()
        } else {

        }

    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        dateCreated = new Date()
        dateUpdated = new Date()
        println("TimeKeeper - beforeInsert workStart: "+workStart)
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        println("TimeKeeper - beforeUpdate workStart: "+workStart)
        dateUpdated = new Date()
    }

    static constraints = {
        dateCreated nullable:true
        workStart nullable:true
        workEnd nullable:true
    }
}
```

The service:

```
@Transactional
class TimeKeeperService {

    def TimeKeeper getTimeKeeper() {
        TimeKeeper.findByName('MAIN')
    }

    def TimeKeeper initialize() {
        def TimeKeeper TK = getTimeKeeper()
        TK.initialize()
    //    def s = TK.save(flush:true)
    //    println("TimeKeeperService - initialize - save: "+s )
       return TK
    }

    def TimeKeeper workStart() {
       def TimeKeeper TK = getTimeKeeper()
       TK.workStart()
       println("TimeKeeperService - validate workStart: "+TK.validate())
    //   TK.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
         println("TimeKeeperService - workStart: "+TK.workStart+" Errors: "+TK.hasErrors())
       return TK
   }
```

When the object is created from bootstrap it works - object is created and saved.
But the service methods `initialize` and `workStart` does not save even if I make the :

```
tk.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

in bootstrap.

But if I set the properties in bootstrap and then call save it works.

```
    tk.workStart = new Date()
    tk.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```

I've struggled for hours with this without success. So I will be very happy if I could get some help solving this.

Comment: version of Grails?

Comment: The version is: 3.3.0

Comment: Your service is transnational annotated, if there is something issue it rollback the trsansaction(will not save the data), try with temporary commenting @Transactional

Comment: I tested that but it didn't help. I called validate() but there nothing wrong, it returned true, so there must be something else that's wrong. It's probably something simple but I can't see it.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem in Grails 3.3.0. Call to methods inside the domain does not make the instance as `dirty`. For an workaround I tried to set the value in controller and it worked from there :(

If you debug, you may see, the value is changed but the instance is not updated as hibernate didn't find it as `dirty`

I suspect its a bug in Grails 3.3.0

I have the gradle properties -

```
grailsVersion=3.3.0
gormVersion=6.1.6.RELEASE
gradleWrapperVersion=3.5
```

Comment: I have the same versions - and the same experience. But if it's a bug - it's strange that no one else claimed that.

Comment: do you have any more investigations?

Comment: No, for the moment I'm stuck. But I can add the fact that the TimeKeepers beforeUpdate-method is never called in hese cases. It's called when you make a save in the controller or bootstrap.

Comment: I love you devdb, you beautiful human being. I was tearing my hair for hours before seeing your response (on grails 3.3.6). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I see some problem in your service method code -

```
def TimeKeeper initialize() {
    def TimeKeeper TK = getTimeKeeper()
    TK.initialize()
//    def s = TK.save(flush:true)
//    println("TimeKeeperService - initialize - save: "+s )
   return TK
}
```

It appears that this method will be called recursively without save being called anytime.

Comment: No, it's the timekeepers initialize that is called not the TimeKepperService.initialize. If it had been recursive it should have made the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite possible that your service method to return null instead of a TimeKeeper you are expecting it to return

```
    def TimeKeeper getTimeKeeper() {
        TimeKeeper.findByName('MAIN')
    }
```

This will method will simply return null if it can't find a TimeKeeper given the constraints.

I would modify this method so that it is guaranteed to return a TimeKeeper

```
def TimeKeeper getTimeKeeper() {
        TimeKeeper.findOrCreateByName('MAIN')
    }
```

Comment: No, it always returns the object and I logged the time values in TimeKeeper and the time is always updated with the correct time. The save also return the object with correct values but the object is never saved into the DB.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
hibernate:
    flush:
        mode: AUTO
```

in your `application.yml`